# How to set delete function to In active the values from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, delete-row

I have delete function on my controller. My function deletes from the database and i works fine, but now i don't want it to permanently delete if from the database, but just set it to in active and not display it. but on database it will be existing.

I have a column called Active and it is 1. How can i make it in active not permanenlety delete it.

here is my code on the controller;

```
    public ActionResult Deletefunction(Part model)
    {
        try
        {
            using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
            {
                Part del = db.Parts.Where(c => c.id == model.PartId).FirstOrDefault();
                db.Parts.Remove(del);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: Assuming Active is a bit field, 1 = true, 0 = false. What exactly prevents you from doing just that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a column called Active on your Part object. You simply change the delete statement to an update as so;

```
   public ActionResult Deletefunction(Part model)
    {
        try
        {
            using (dbContext db = new dbContext())
            {
                Part del = db.Parts.Where(c => c.id == model.PartId).FirstOrDefault();
                // Changed from Delete to update
                del.Active = 0;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Note that anywhere you display these, if you want to not show inactive ones, you will have to add a where clause like;

```
var onlyActiveParts = db.Parts.Where(p => p.Active == 1);
```